# Ionic2 ion-toggle get value on ionChange

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have this toggle here:

```
<ion-toggle (ionChange)="notify(value)"></ion-toggle>
```

When I click this I want to call the method notify passing the toggle value by parameter. How I can get the toggle value?

Thank you!

Comment: try notify($event)

Comment: and then in your function `notify(event:any) { console.log(event.target.value); }`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just like you can see in [Ionic2 Docs - Toggle](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toggle/Toggle/), a better way to do that would be to **bind the toggle to a property** from your component by using **ngModel**.

Component code:

```
public isToggled: boolean;

// ...

constructor(...) {
  this.isToggled = false;
}

public notify() {
  console.log("Toggled: "+ this.isToggled); 
}
```

View:

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="isToggled" (ionChange)="notify()"></ion-toggle>
```

This way, you don't need to send the value because it's already a property from your component and you can always get the value by using `this.isToggled`.

**UPDATE**

Just like **[@GFoley83](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654708/gfoley83)** mentioned on his comment:

> Be very careful with ionChange when it's bound directly to `ngModel`. The notify method will get called when the value bound to `ngModel` changes, either from the view via someone clicking the toggle or in your component via code e.g. when you do a fresh GET call. I had an issue recently whereby clicking the toggle triggered a `PATCH`, this meant that every other client would automatically trigger a `PATCH` when the data bound to the toggle changed.
>
> We used:
> `<ion-toggle [ngModel]="isToggled" (ngModelChange)="notifyAndUpdateIsToggled()"></ion-toggle>` to get around this

Comment: Thanks @sebaferreras, this helped!

Comment: this works thanks, you can also remove the round brackets from [(ngModel)]

Comment: You're right @Ruben! I just left it there like this to keep it consistent with Ionic docs, but thanks to bring that out :)

Comment: Be very careful with `ionChange` when it's bound directly to `ngModel`. The `notify` method will get called when the value bound to `ngModel` changes, either from the view via someone clicking the toggle or in your component via code e.g. when you do a fresh `GET` call. I had an issue recently whereby clicking the toggle triggered a `PATCH`, this meant that every other client would automatically trigger a `PATCH` when the data bound to the toggle changed. We used `<ion-toggle [ngModel]="isToggled" (ngModelChange)="notifyAndUpdateIsToggled()"></ion-toggle>` to get around this.

Comment: Thanks @GFoley83 I've added your comment to the answer :)

Comment: I have used (click) to get ngModel value from ion-toggle in .ts file, but it had random mis-launch sometimes. 
However, after changed to (ngModelChange), the problem solved.

Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that @QinWang :)

Comment: How would you go about this if the toggle is dynamically generated with ngFor where the amount of toggle to be generated is unknown. This method only works for static toggles or if you always have a set amount.

Answer (score 18):

You can use **`$event`** in **`ionChange`**.

View:

```
<ion-toggle (ionChange)="notify($event)"></ion-toggle>
```

Controller:

```
notify(event) {
   console.log(event.checked);   
}
```

Comment: That's `undefined` in Ionic 5

Comment: This is not valid in latest version. Use the ngModel and onChange combined. or use event.currentTarget.checked.

Comment: Solution for Ionic 5: https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/get-ion-toggle-value-ionic5-and-angular-12

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways of checking.

First one is like @Chathuranga Silva suggested

**html**

`<ion-toggle (ionChange)="notify($event)"></ion-toggle>`

**ts**

`notify(event: any) { console.log("toggled: "+event.target.checked); }`

Second one would be something like this:

**html**

`<ion-toggle (ionChange)="notify()" [checked]="isToggled"></ion-toggle>`

**ts**

```
var isToggled: boolean = true;

notify() {
  console.log("toggled: "+ this.isToggled); 
}
```

Which one you pick is up to you, I'd recommend the second one since it will be easier to manipulate the toggle in the constructor/onInit, and easier using this value outside the `notify()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $event in ionChange.

View:

```
<ion-toggle (ionChange)="onChange($event)"></ion-toggle>
```

Controller:

```
onChange(ev) {
   console.log(ev.target.checked);   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
<ion-toggle id="availabilityButton" [(ngModel)]="setOffOrnot"
(ionChange)="setAvailability()"></ion-toggle>

setAvailability(e) {
  this.setOffOrnot = ...
}
```